# Images + Videos mixed in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

Am trying to check both images and Videos availability in the `RecyclerView`, but the challenge is the `VideoView` is the only one Visible in all the items List , the `ImageView` is not visible at all, what i want is to check if the Image is present in the ImageView the Videoview **GOES**, and when the Video is available in the `VideoView` the `ImageView` **Goes**.

Am developing an App which posts both Videos and Images and retrieves them in  the same `RecyclerView` , so please help me how can i achieve this

Below is my code but it doesn't work :

```
boolean hasDrawable = (viewHolder.imagePost.getDrawable()!= null);

String hasVideo_string =(String)viewHolder.videoLayout.getTag();
boolean hasVideo = Boolean.parseBoolean(hasVideo_string);

if(hasDrawable){
   viewHolder.setTitle(model.getEventTitle());
   viewHolder.setDesc(model.getEventDescription());
   viewHolder.setImage(c, model.getEventImage());
   viewHolder.videoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }

else if(hasVideo) {
  viewHolder.setTitle(model.getEventTitle());
  viewHolder.setDesc(model.getEventDescription());
  viewHolder.setVideo(c, model.getEventVideo());
  viewHolder.imagePost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

This is how i set my Image and Video in a `ViewHolder` Class

```
public void setImage(final Context c,final String imageUrl){
    //
    Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imagePost, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                    //Reloading an image again ...
                    Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                            .into(imagePost);
                }
            });

        }
```

and the video (I used a Library called FullscreenVideoLayout , its like a VideoView but much customized)

```
public void setVideo(final Context c, final String videoUrl){

   // videoLayout.setActivity(this);
   // videoLayout.setActivity(get);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    try {
        videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoLayout.setTag(videoUrl);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the Full `ViewHolder` class

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        View mView;
        private ImageView imagePost;
        private FullscreenVideoLayout videoLayout;
          private VideoView videoView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
          imagePost =(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
           videoLayout = (FullscreenVideoLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_video);

        }
        public void setTitle(String title){

            TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);

        }

        public void setDesc(String desc){

            TextView post_desc = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }


        public void setImage(final Context c,final String imageUrl){

       //

            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imagePost, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                    //Reloading an image again ...
                    Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                            .into(imagePost);
                }
            });

        }

        public void setVideo(final Context c, final String videoUrl){


           // videoLayout.setActivity(this);
           // videoLayout.setActivity(get);

            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
            try {
                videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                videoLayout.setTag(videoUrl);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

            }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the hasVideo/hasDrawable flag is correctly set up? Where/How do you set the videoLayout tag and imagePost drawable?

Comment: I have updated my post @daemontus , check how i was set them

Comment: Ok, well, my guess is that by the time you call getDrawable(), picasso hasn't yet set anything into the view (it does a lot of stuff in the background, sometimes it is hard to tell when exactly are certain things going to happen). So my recommendation would be to do something like this:
boolean hasImage = /*whatever condition you use to decide whether to call setImage in the first place*/;
boolean hasVideo = /*whatever condition you use to decide whether to call setVideo*/;
if (hasImage) { setImage(); imagePost.setVisibility(INVISIBLE) } else if (hasVideo) { same for video }

Comment: @daemontus , thanks for your explanation, but it has confused me abit , can you please try to edit an answer for me i have also posted the Full `Viewholder` class, am still a beginner in this stuff. Thanks

Comment: @daemontus, please help me on this , am stuck , it will be my pleasure for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using `Firebase`, so since you are getting the `Urls` of both Videos and Images `getEventImage()` and `getEventVideo()` , just check the `Urls` if they are Empty and Remove the Visibility of the `ImageView` and `VideoView`.

Below is the sample code , Try this out:

```
 public void setImage(final Context c,final String imageUrl){

            try {
                if (imageUrl!=null) {
                    //

                    Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imagePost, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                            //Reloading an image again ...
                            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).error(R.mipmap.add_btn).placeholder(R.mipmap.add_btn)
                                    .into(imagePost);
                        }
                    });





                } else {

                    imagePost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }

        }

        public void setVideo(final Context c, final String videoUrl){
            try {
                if (videoUrl!=null) {
                    try {
                        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                        try {
                            videoLayout.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                            videoLayout.setTag(videoUrl);
                            String hasVideo_string = (String) videoLayout.getTag();
                            boolean hasVideo = Boolean.parseBoolean(hasVideo_string);


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error :" + e);
                    }

                } else {
                    videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }


        }
```

Hope it works for you .